# Как проверить работу сайта?

Tags: java, android

Есть определенный адрес сайта, который надо проверять на работоспособность. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал такой вариант, но он всегда говорит, что сайт недоступен.

```
boolean isHostReachable(String address) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(address).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 200)
            return true;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Так 200 как раз и есть положительный ответ. Надо как раз наоборот - ``if (responseCode == 200)``

Comment: Все равно не работает, присылает false

Comment: Ну посмотрите какой там ответ приходит.

Comment: А как насчёт postman?

Comment: Сайты надо проверять с помощью броузера